# Django custom registration: how to set a default password and use first name + last name as username

Tags: python, mysql, django

Someone wants me to make a registration form with no email, and just first name, last name and date of birth. So I decided to do this:

`username = request.POST['first_name'] + '__' + request.POST['last_name']`

I know we need to have a unique field in Django, so a person with the same name will cause problems. But this is how he wants it done (not many users will be using it).

So how do I populate Django's AbstractBaseUser with a username as above and a default password?

The idea is to get a `Doctor` who is already logged in to register a new `Patient` with just first name, last name, and date of birth.

`models.py`:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    USER_TYPE = (('doc', 'Doctor'), ('pat', 'Patient'))
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, )
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=254, choices=USER_TYPE)
    first_time = models.NullBooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

`forms.py:`

```
class patientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

class patientProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patients
        fields = ('dob', 'condition')
```

`views.py:`

```
@login_required
def new_patient(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        patient_form = patientForm(data=request.POST)
        patient_profile = patientProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        if patient_form.is_valid() and patient_profile.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['first_name'] + '__' + request.POST['last_name']
            user = patient_form.save() #Error here: (1062, “Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'”)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = patient_profile.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.doctor = request.user
            profile.save()
            registered = True

        else:
            print patient_form.errors, patient_profile.errors
    else:
        patient_form = patientForm()
        patient_profile = patientProfileForm()

    return render_to_response(
        'new-patient.html',
        {'patient_form': patient_form, 'patient_profile': patient_profile, 'registered': registered},
        context)
```

How do I add the username in the format mentioned earlier when saving the form? I get the error:
`(1062, “Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'”)` (see above where this happens)

Comment: Consider using slugify of firstname, and lastname - if found, append a number

Comment: will do, however, I'm a noob in Django, wanted to know how to add the generated username to be saved into the database.

Comment: You have made remarkable progress to be considered a noob :). You could add the username field in the `clean` method.

Comment: I'm actually one level above noob :). Do you have any links to documentation about the clean method? Thanks

Comment: Let me try to answer this - You might have to tweak it to your requriements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to override the [`clean` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) to set the username field until found. This might not be the exact code you need, but you get the idea.

```
class patientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        fullname = "%s-%s" % (cd.get('first_name'), cd.get('last_name'))
        username = slugify(fullname)

        while True:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            except:
                username = username + '-copy' #Or changes this to a counter.
            else: 
                break


        cd['username'] = fullname
        return cd
```